# How to color each two rows in pdfmake table

Tags: javascript, formatting, modulo, conditional-operator, pdfmake

I'm triyng to achieve a simple thing normally but i'm am using PDFMAKE library to make pdf from data.
In the documentation for the tables there is an example for striped tables like this :

```
{
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            body: [
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
            ]
        },
        layout: {
            fillColor: function (rowIndex, node, columnIndex) {
                return (rowIndex % 2 === 0) ? '#CCCCCC' : null;
            }
        }
    },
```

But I wanna color with #CCCCCC every two rows not one rows then switch color.
I tried many things, but no one has worked.
It seems that the function loop through each column of each rows.

Please someone know how to do this with pdfmake library ?

Comment: two rows ` #CCCCCC` then `null` and the again ` #CCCCCC` and so on?

Comment: Hey, please check my answer, how it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add `return (rowIndex % 3 != 0) ? '#CCCCCC' : null;`

Try this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  console.log(((i+1) % 3 != 0) ? '#CCCCCC' : null);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you were close from what i wanted. I have a two rows headers wich have to be colored in gray first then we start to swotch the colors each 2 rows. With i % 3 the gray start at the 2nd row. But thank you :D

Comment: Let me modify it.

Answer (score 2):

The following will produce two after two

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(Math.floor(i/2)%2==0){
    console.log('#CCCCCC');
  }
  else{
    console.log(null);
  }
}
```

So your code should be

```
fillColor: function (rowIndex, node, columnIndex) {
    return (Math.floor(rowIndex/2)%2==0) ? '#CCCCCC' : null;
}
```